# What's wrong about this question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Why (lots of) developers prefer whitespacing everywhere?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/395568/why-lots-of-developers-prefer-whitespacing-everywhere)

The question is about coding-style,
I confirmed that I've asked the question in the correct site
(since I've already read some discussion about correctly using whitespaces in coding on this site)
And also I've attentively tagged the question correctly.

But these questions were deleted very soon.

[image: Question screenshot]

Hmm, I hoped I can understand, did I asked my question in some incorrect way?
Or did my question hurt some friends who has worked on developing code formatters?
If so, I want to say, I feel really really sorry to you!
Code formatters are really cool for me!
(Although can't dismiss those excessive whitespaces)

Or is it just bad if I asking question about hurting popular customs?
At least making some discussion?
I can really understand some people dislike it and downvoting it,
but why should these question been never asked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although questions about coding style are on-topic here, this question falls squarely into the category of [questions that aren't a good fit for the question and answer format](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Among other things, questions that are polling people's opinions or seeking a discussion don't tend to fit well in this format. Instead, questions should be focused on understanding and solving a specific problem that you face.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try to ask in correct way next time!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have also been unlucky in that prefered whitespace formatting is an old question that has been burning for ages and has religious adherents to virtually any format you can imagine.

If it's the first time you have come across it then yeah I would ask the same thing. If its the 10002nd time you've come across it then you don't want to get involved.